# Encontrar um objeto no array que possui uma chave específica

Tags: angular, typescript

Tenho o seguinte array de objetos:

```
specifications: Array(63)
0: {key: "1", value: null}
1: {key: "11\uFF0E11", value: null}
2: {key: "155\uFF0E50", value: null}
3: {key: "2", value: null}
4: {key: "200\uFF0E00", value: null}
5: {key: "2222\uFF0E22", value: null}
6: {key: "222\uFF0E22", value: null}
7: {key: "22\uFF0E22", value: null}
8: {key: "24\uFF0E24", value: null}
9: {key: "25\uFF0E25", value: null}
10: {key: "26\uFF0E26", value: null}
11: {key: "27\uFF0E27", value: null}
12: {key: "28\uFF0E28", value: null}
13: {key: "29\uFF0E29", value: null}
14: {key: "3", value: null}
15: {key: "3000\uFF0E00", value: null}
16: {key: "300\uFF0E00", value: null}
17: {key: "30\uFF0E30", value: null}
18: {key: "31\uFF0E31", value: null}
19: {key: "32\uFF0E32", value: null}
20: {key: "33", value: null}
21: {key: "333\uFF0E33", value: null}
22: {key: "Valor", value: 14}
```

Preciso de encontrar nesse `array` a chave que possui nome `Valor` e atribuir a uma variável o valor contido na chave `value`.

Pensei em fazer da seguinte forma:

```
for(let i=0;i<this.specifications.length;i++){
   if(this.especifications[i].key == "Valor"){
      minhaVariavel = this.specifications[i].value
   }
}
```

Funciona, porém gostaria de saber se o TypeScript provê alguma outra forma, talvez mais enxuta, de conseguir encontrar esse objeto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Método find.

```
minhaVariavel = this.specifications.find(s => s.key === 'Valor').value
```

Documentação:

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar o método [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) para trazer somente os elementos que possuem a chave desejada:

```
let specsFiltradas = specifications.filter(spec => spec.key == 'Valor');
```

Isso retorna outro array, contendo somente os elementos que possuem a chave `key` igual a `'Valor'`.

Para obter os valores, podemos encadear uma chamada de [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), para transformar cada elemento do array no seu respectivo valor:

```
let valores = specifications.filter(spec => spec.key == 'Valor').map(spec => spec.value);
```

Com isso, `valores` será um array contendo os valores. Se tiver mais de um objeto cuja chave `key` seja `'Valor'`, todos serão retornados. Ex:

```js
let specifications = [
    { key: "32\uFF0E32", value: null },
    { key: "Valor", value: 15 },
    { key: "333\uFF0E33", value: null },
    { key: "Valor", value: 14 }
];
let valores = specifications.filter(spec => spec.key == 'Valor').map(spec => spec.value);
console.log(valores); // [15, 14]
```

Se nenhum dos elementos tiver `key` igual a `'Valor'`, o array será vazio.

---

As outras respostas sugeriram usar [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) ou [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), que também funciona.

A diferença é que `find` retorna somente a primeira ocorrência (se tiver mais objetos com `key` igual a `'Valor'`, apenas a primeira é retornada):

```js
let specifications = [
    { key: "32\uFF0E32", value: null },
    { key: "Valor", value: 15 },
    { key: "333\uFF0E33", value: null },
    { key: "Valor", value: 14 }
];
let valor = specifications.find(spec => spec.key == 'Valor').value;
console.log(valor); // 15
```

Além disso, você deve verificar se o retorno é `undefined` antes de pegar o valor.

```js
let specifications = [
    { key: "32\uFF0E32", value: null },
    { key: "abc", value: 15 },
    { key: "333\uFF0E33", value: null },
    { key: "def", value: 14 }
];

// não existe key igual a Valor, find retorna undefined e
// ao tentar pegar o valor diretamente, dá um TypeError
try {
    let valor = specifications.find(spec => spec.key == 'Valor').value;
} catch(e) {
    console.log(e.name, e.message); // TypeError Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
}

// então tem que verificar se find retornou algo
let spec = specifications.find(spec => spec.key == 'Valor');
if (spec) { // nesse caso não entra no if
    let valor = spec.value;
    console.log(valor);
} else {
    console.log('Valor não encontrado');
}
```

E `forEach` vai percorrer todos os elementos, então vai pegar a última ocorrência:

```js
let specifications = [
    { key: "32\uFF0E32", value: null },
    { key: "Valor", value: 15 },
    { key: "333\uFF0E33", value: null },
    { key: "Valor", value: 14 }
];

let valor;
specifications.forEach(item => {
    if(item.key === "Valor"){
        valor = item.value;
    }
});
console.log(valor); // 14
```

Mas se quer a primeira ocorrência, por que não usar um `for` simples mesmo?

```js
let specifications = [
    { key: "32\uFF0E32", value: null },
    { key: "Valor", value: 15 },
    { key: "333\uFF0E33", value: null },
    { key: "Valor", value: 14 }
];

let valor = undefined;
for (const item of specifications) {
    if (item.key === "Valor") {
        valor = item.value;
        break; // encontrei, sai do loop
    }
}
if (valor !== undefined)
    console.log(valor); // 15
else
    console.log('valor não encontrado');
```

É claro que se tiver apenas um elemento que satisfaça a condição, tanto faz o método usado.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.specifications.forEach( item ->{
  if(item.key === "Valor"){
      minhaVariavel = item.value
   }
})
```

Sempre lembre de utilizar `===`, pois assim ele verifica o tipo da variável e o valor. Utilizando `==`, a comparaçao é somente do valor, então `2 == '2'` retornaria `true`.