# Como verificar se existe um indice de um array dentro de outro para evitar duplicar?

Tags: array, angular

Bom dia, essa é a minha primeira pergunta por aqui

Estou fazendo uma app em angular usando a api google books e preciso de uma ajuda..
Tenho um botão que adiciona indices do array de livros para o array de favoritos, mas preciso evitar que o mesmo livro seja adicionado novamente aos favoritos, segue o código
A minha dúvida é sobre a condição que devo usar no if caso o livro já exista nos favoritos

```
  books = []
  favs = []

  addFav(i: number) {
    const title = this.books[i].volumeInfo.title

    if(???) {
      this.toastr.error('Este livro já consta nos seus favoritos!')
    } else {
      this.favs.push(this.books[i])
      this.toastr.success(`O livro "${title}" foi adicionado aos seus favoritos!`)
      console.log(this.favs)
    }
  }
```

Comment: use o `find` do objeto array para verificar isso. Aqui no site tem várias perguntas sobre isso, veja essa que vai te ajudar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/363949/57220

Comment: obrigado amigo, vou dar uma olhada

Comment: Voce tambem pode usar um Set que evita duplicatas

Comment: const exists = this.favs.find(i => i.volumeInfo.title == title) fiz isso e passei o exists pra dentro do if, deu certo! muito obrigado

Comment: boa isso mesmo ;)

Answer (score 0):

Então, se reparares: tu já fazes isso:

```
const title = this.books[i].volumeInfo.title
```

esta linha irá falhar se o index `i` na array `this.books` nao existir com a mensagem "cannot get .volumeInfo of undefined"

isto diz-te que se fizeres

```
if (this.books[i]) {
  // isto quer dizer que o livro com o index "i" existe no "this.books"
}
```

então, se negarmos essa condição:

```
if (!this.books[i]) {
  // NAO existe o index "i" na array "this.books"
}
```

Podes, no entanto, fazer um check antes. A função ficaria assim:

```
books = [];
favs = [];
addFav(i: number) {
    const book = this.books[i]; // criamos uma variavel que nos retorne o "livro" em si

    if(book) { // vemos se a variavel tem um valor "truthy"
      this.toastr.error('Este livro já consta nos seus favoritos!')
    } else {
      const title = book.volumeInfo.title; // podemos usar a variavel criada anteriormente
      this.favs.push(this.books[i])
      this.toastr.success(`O livro "${title}" foi adicionado aos seus favoritos!`)
      console.log(this.favs)
    }
  }
```